# How do I pass an argument to the macro annotation?

Tags: scalameta

I want get StaticAnnotation's parameters defined as:

```
class Log(logTag: List[LogTag] = Info() :: Nil )
         (implicit logger: String => Unit = a => {println(a)})
  extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation {
  inline def apply(defn: Any): Any = meta {
    val logTag = ??? //todo
    val logger = ??? //todo
  }
}
```

How to get the `logTag` and `logger` Function values in `meta` block? 
I have seem [meta tutorials](http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#HowdoIpassanargumenttothemacroannotation?) about this point. But the `Lit` just refers `Int`/`Double`,etc, rather then custom class type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deconstruct `this` as a `scala.meta.Tree` to get the class parameters. See http://scalameta.org/tutorial/#HowdoIpassanargumenttothemacroannotation%3F for an example